# UIVIew inside UIScrollView bounces back

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

MY app is for iPad using Storyboards with two scenes.  On one scene, I have a UIScrollView that contains a UIVIew.  It scrolls, but bounces back immediately, rendering itself useless.  The size of the UIScrollView is 768x590; the size of the UIView is 768x1590; ContentSize of the UIScrollView is 768x590.  This is an image of the UIScrollView settings:
[image]

(I have looked at SO and Google for the past 6 hours, tried a lot of stuff, but nothing works.  I have also done a CMD + Option + K (Clean) several times, and that didn't help either.

Why does it not scroll properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found what works for me!

> When you embed a view into a UIScrollView in InterfaceBuilder, then
>   there's a constraint automatically set. If your view is "longer" than
>   the screen in portrait, it wont scroll at all.
>
> But if you rotate the screen, you'll notice the ability to scroll a
>   little.
>
> To get UIScrollView going in AutoLayout look into your constraints.
>
> Find "Vertical Space - Scroll View - View" and set it from "constant"
>   to "auto" - fixed everything for me.

Thanks for your help... I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Your scrollView height is less than the uiview which is the subview in your case of scrollview and for scrolling it fully you will have to set  your **scrollview contentSize height**  more than the height of the view you are scrolling in it,please give a check on this point.

Comment: If I take the iPad Simulator and turn it landscape mode, it sort of works (doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom and stay there).  When I put it back in portrait mode, it doesn't work at all.